# how to convert zeroes to date

Tags: java, date

i get the single value from String array.this single value have zeroes.i want convert this zeroes to date and gettime...

```
String followupdate2="";
for(int i=1;i<2;i++){
    followupdate2=followupdate1[i];
    System.out.println("--------------"+followupdate2);
}
System.out.println("---------outer-----"+followupdate2);
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
Date followupdate3=format1.parse(followupdate2);
long followupdate4=followupdate3.getTime();
```

`followupdate2` have `00-000-00`

i want convert `followupdate2` to date ....

i want get `long followupdate4=followupdate3.getTime();`

error is:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "00-000-00"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What do you want `000000000` to be converted to?

Comment: i want 000000000 converted to date format..........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are feeding your program bad input. The output is TELLING YOU that you are feeding it bad input.

**Use a try-catch block and deal with it.**

```
SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
long followupdate4;
try {
  Date followupdate3=format1.parse(followupdate2);
  followupdate4 = followupdate3.getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
  followupdate4 = 0; //Whatever you want here.
}
```

Comment: this followupdate4 value compare with another date gettime.........so i want followupdate4 value please help me..

Comment: followupdate4 is now `0` or whatever you want it to be. What you are doing is like saying format1.parse("VELOCIRAPTOR") and expecting Java to give you a date out of it. That's nonsense.